Efficient influence function with interventions that depend on the natural value of the exposure
Figure A1 shows a SWIG with L being a confounder of the association between exposure X and outcome Y.

I am dealing with an intervention on X that modifies it according to its natural value (e.g., not a deterministic static regime where everyone is set to 1). For instance, if the natural value of X is 2, then reduce it to 1, otherwise leave it as is. The causal effect of interest (g-formula) is defined below (for ease of notation, I represent the intervened upon node as $\tilde{x}$, instead of marking it in red):
\begin{equation}
\Psi = \sum_{l, x, \tilde{x}} E \left[ Y | X = \tilde{x}, L=l \right] p \left( X = \tilde{x} | X=x, L=l \right) p \left( X=x | L=l \right) p(l).
\label{eq:swig_1e1t_n}
\end{equation}
I want to build a doubly robust estimator, specifically an augmented inverse probability weighting (AIPW) estimator. For this reason, I want to write down the efficient influence function (EIF) of my causal parameter. I am following the tips found in Kennedy 2023 (here). For ease of notation, I will define $\mu(x,l) = E \left[ Y | X=x, L=l \right]$ and $\pi(x|l) = p \left( X=x | L=l \right)$. The EIF ($\mathbb{IF}$) can be written as follows:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{IF}{(\Psi)} &= \sum_{l, x, \tilde{x}} \mathbb{IF}{\left\{ \mu(\tilde{x},l) \right\}} p \left( X = \tilde{x} | X=x, L=l \right) \pi(x|l) p(l) + \mu(\tilde{x},l) p \left( X = \tilde{x} | X=x, L=l \right) \pi(x|l) \mathbb{IF}{\left\{ p(l) \right\}}.
\label{eq:swig_1e1t_n_eif}
\end{align}
For the first term in the summation of the EIF, we have:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{IF}{(\Psi)}_1 &= \sum_{l, x, \tilde{x}} \frac{\mathbb{1}(X=\tilde{x}, L=l)}{p(X=\tilde{x}, L=l)} \left\{ Y^{\tilde{x}} - \mu(\tilde{x},l) \right\} p \left( X = \tilde{x} | X=x, L=l \right) \pi(x|l) p(l) \nonumber \\
&= \sum_{x} \frac{p \left( \tilde{X} | X=x, L \right) \pi(x|L)}{\pi(\tilde{X} | L)} \left\{ Y^{\tilde{x}} - \mu(\tilde{X},L) \right\}.
\end{align}
For the second term in the summation of the EIF, we have:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{IF}{(\Psi)}_2 &= \sum_{l, x, \tilde{x}} \mu(\tilde{x},l) p \left( X = \tilde{x} | X=x, L=l \right) \pi(x|l) \left\{ \mathbb{1}(L=l) - p(l) \right\} \nonumber \\
&= \sum_{x, \tilde{x}} \mu(\tilde{x},L) p \left( X = \tilde{x} | X=x, L \right) \pi(x|L) - \sum_{l, x, \tilde{x}} \mu(\tilde{x},L=l) p \left( X = \tilde{x} | X=x, L=l \right) \pi(x|l) p(L=l) \nonumber \\
&= \sum_{x, \tilde{x}} \mu(\tilde{x},L) p \left( X = \tilde{x} | X=x, L \right) \pi(x|L) - \Psi.
\end{align}
Putting them together, we obtain:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{IF}{(\Psi)} + \Psi = \sum_{x} \frac{p \left( \tilde{X} | X=x, L \right) \pi(x|L)}{\pi(\tilde{X} | L)} \left\{ Y^{\tilde{x}} - \mu(\tilde{X},L) \right\} + \sum_{x, \tilde{x}} \mu(\tilde{x},L) p \left( X = \tilde{x} | X=x, L \right) \pi(x|L).
\label{eq:swig_1e1t_n_eif_derived}
\end{equation}
There are no similar examples in the review by Kennedy 2023, the closest being a stochastic intervention. I am comparing the EIF I obtain with that found here, specifically the EIF written in the last paragraph of page 15:
\begin{equation}
r(A,L) (Y - m(A,L)) + m(\mathbb{d}(A,L), L) - \theta,
\end{equation}
with $\theta$ being the parameter of interest, $r$ the density ratio defined at the top of page 15, and $m$ the expected outcome given exposure and confounders. The authors use the function $\mathbb{d}$ to define the exposure intervention.
It is clear that my EIF and their is not the same, although similar. One key difference is that in my density ratio (the first term in the summation of the EIF), $\tilde{X}$ is present both in the numerator and denominator. Similarly for $Y^{\tilde{x}}$ and $\mu(\tilde{X}, L)$.
My questions are the following:

Is the g-formula correct, considering my causal question of interest? I believe it is, but I could not compare it to the ones in the mentioned papers since in my case the intervention depends on the natural value of the exposure, thus there is a extra term (namely, the density of the modified exposure given the natural one and confounders).
If the g-formula is correct, is the derivation of the EIF correct? I do not understand how the density ratio ends up being so different. Also, it is not clear to me why in the derivation of the EIF for a stochastic intervention in Kennedy 2023, there is no term for the EIF of the propensity scores. The EIF proposed here should apply to virtually every intervention, according to the authors, so I feel there is an error in mine.


You clearly put a lot of effort into this, but you need to clarify what exactly you are asking. As it stands, I don't think you could get a useful answer here without being more specific about what you need help with.

@Noah You are aright. I spent so much time on this problem that it felt clear but it was not!

If I understand correctly, the target parameter $\Psi_\pi$ is the mean outcome under stochastic policy $\pi(X'\mid X,L)$ where $X$ is the "observational" or "natural" value of $X'$. If so, then the $g$-formula you presented is correct:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Psi_\pi[P] &= \sum_{L,X,X'}\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid L, X'\right]\, \pi(X'\mid L,X)\, p(L,X) \\
&= \sum_{L,X,X',Y} Y\, \frac{p(L,X',Y)\, \pi(X'\mid L,X)\, p(L,X)}{p(L,X')}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $P$ is the underlying distribution of $O=(L,X=X',Y)$ in a fully nonparametric model $P\in\mathfrak{P}$.
Provided some smoothness, regularity, boundedness and positivity conditions, $\Psi$ is pathwise differentiable at $P$. Let $p_\epsilon(O) = \epsilon\,\mathbb{I}(O=O_i)+(1-\epsilon)p(O)$ be a slight fluctuation of $p(O)$ towards the Dirac delta distribution $\mathbb{I}(O=O_i)\equiv \delta_{O_i}(O)$. Then, the influence function of $\Psi$ evaluated at $O_i=(L_i,X_i=X_i',Y_i)$ can be computed as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
D_\Psi(O_i) &= \sum_{L,X,X',Y}Y\, \pi(X'\mid L, X)\, \underbrace{\frac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}\epsilon}\frac{p_\epsilon(L,X',Y)\, p_\epsilon(L, X)}{p_\epsilon(L,X')}\bigg\vert_{\epsilon=0}}_{\chi(O_i)}\\
\chi(O_i) &= \frac{p(L,X)}{p(L,X')}[\mathbb{I}(L=L_i,X'=X'_i,Y=Y_i)-p(L,X',Y)]\\
&\,+ \frac{p(L,X',Y)}{p(L,X')}[\mathbb{I}(L=L_i,X=X_i)-p(L,X)]\\
&\,- \frac{p(L,X',Y)\, p(L,X)}{p(L,X')^2}[\mathbb{I}(L=L_i,X'=X_i')-p(L,X')] \\
&= -p(Y\mid L,X')\,p(L,X)\\
&\,+ \frac{p(L,X)}{p(L,X')}\mathbb{I}(L=L_i,X'=X'_i,Y=Y_i)\\
&\,+ \frac{p(L,X',Y)}{p(L,X')}\mathbb{I}(L=L_i,X=X_i)\\
&\,- \frac{p(L,X',Y)\, p(L,X)}{p(L,X')^2}\mathbb{I}(L=L_i,X'=X_i') 
\end{aligned}
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
D_\Psi(O_i) &= -\Psi+ \sum_{X}Y_i\,\pi(X'_i\mid L_i,X)\frac{p(L_i,X)}{p(L_i,X'_i)}\\
&\,+\sum_{X',Y}Y\, \pi(X'\mid L_i,X_i)\, p(Y\mid L_i,X')\\
&\, -\sum_{X,Y}Y\, \pi(X'_i\mid L_i,X)\, p(Y\mid L_i,X'_i) \, \frac{p(L_i,X)}{p(L_i,X_i')}\\
&= -\Psi + \frac{Y_i-\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid L_i,X'_i\right]}{p(X_i'\mid L_i)}\sum_{X}\pi(X_i'\mid L_i,X)\,p(X\mid L_i)\\
&\,+\sum_{X'}\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid L_i,X'\right]\, \pi(X'\mid L_i,X_i)\\
&= -\Psi + r(L_i,X'_i)\left[Y_i-m(L_i,X'_i)\right]+\mathbb{E}_{X'\sim\pi} m(L_i,X')
\end{aligned}
$$
where:
$$
\begin{aligned}
r(L_i,X_i') &= \frac{\sum_{X}\pi(X_i'\mid L_i,X)\,p(X\mid L_i)}{p(X_i'\mid L_i)}\\
m(L_i,X'_i) & = \mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid L_i,X'_i\right]\\
\mathbb{E}_{X'\sim\pi} m(L_i,X') &= \sum_{X'}m(L_i,X')\, \pi(X'\mid L_i,X_i)
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice that, if the policy would be deterministic $\mathbb{I}(X'=X)$, then the influence function would collapse to the classical one for the mean potential outcome, with:
$$
\begin{aligned}
r(L_i,X_i') &= \frac{1}{p(X_i'\mid L_i)}\\
\mathbb{E}_{X'\sim\pi} m(L_i,X') &= m(L_i,X'_i)
\end{aligned}
$$

Thank you for the detailed answer! I believe the two derivations almost coincide. The only difference I could spot is that the 2nd summation of my IF is over $x$ and $x'$, and it has $p(X=x|L)$, which yours does not. It is also not clear to me why we do not include the IF of $p(x'|l,x)$. The EIF in Diaz should also apply to stochastic interventions depending on the natural value, but it is very different from this...

@wrong_path You mean why $\pi(X'\mid L, X)$ is not fluctuated? That is because the policy acts as a constraint on the (semiparametric) statistical model. In other words, the policy is fixed, cannot be fluctuated.

I believe one mistake I made is that for $\mathbb{IF} (\Psi)_2$, I took the IF only of $p(L=l)$, whereas I should have taken the IF of $p(X=x|L=l)p(L=l) = p(X=x,L=l)$.

Do you have any recommendations for deriving similar EIFs but in a longitudinal setting (i.e., repeated measures of exposures and confounders)? Using Gateaux derivatives leads to very large expression, and I could not find "tricks" as in Kennedy. Thank you.

@wrong_path Will you be working under sequential ignorability? If so, you could express the query in a $t$-invariant manner by conditioning on the accumulated history $H_t$ of treatment and outcomes before $t$. This would make expressions shorter and easier to manipulate. Some people use bar notation, as well, to indicate history.
